# Reading from a text file into HTML

Tags: html

I want to make a small html based game for a school project. I would like to be able to extract data from a text file, then insert if necessary in order to save data. So my question is: 
What programming language can i use in order to read from a .txt file into a HTML page?

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Python (the easiest), Ruby, C++ (hard enough)

Comment: I have  a bit experience in c++ actually. But how can i use it with html?

Comment: if you want to generate this HTML 'on the fly', then you probably don't want to use C++. In other cases (eg. you generate that once and then use static HTMLs) it's OK if you know C++ well enough.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be php. There are dozens of methods to achieve this. Note, however, that this task will be much easier to accomplish if your text file is on the same domain as the code. This is best for single levels that dont change.

### Php

In php, you could use

```
$file = fopen('pathtofile.txt', r);
```

Note that the second parameter, **r**, signifies that the file should be readable. Use **w** if you want to write to the file.

There are a *lot* of tutorials on google for this.

### Ajax

If you'd prefer not to use php, Ajax is also available to you via javascript. This method is best if you need to change files while the game is running, ie loading new levels.

```
$.ajax({
   method: 'get',
   path: 'pathtofile.txt',
   success: function(data){
      //level info is in **data**
   },
   error: function(x, h, r){
      // this will display error info, ie file does not exist
   }
})
```

The code above most likely won't work, it is intended as a demo. Again, there are plenty of examples for this on google.

Have fun and happy coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will indeed use this method.